# Search engine for Stack Overflow

Tags: app

[image]

**About**

[Stackse](http://stackse.com)  (**Stack** Overflow **s**earch **e**ngine) is search engine for Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault and some other sites, that allows searching with special characters. The goal was to build a small search engine from scratch as challenging hobby project. Hope this will be useful.

**Contact**

[This google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/stackse) should be used for feedback.

**Technology and license**

C#, leveldb on Windows. Closed-source.